# Rails getting CORS error when requesting javascript from the local server

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cors

I'm using head.js to load a dialog polyfill for browsers that don't support it. I've got `head.js` in my `/app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file and I'm trying to load the polyfill from `/app/assets/javascripts/build/polyfills/dialog-polyfill.js` But I keep getting the following cross origin error

```
ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest in BaseController#index
Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.

Rails.root: /Users/rich/IdeaProjects/test_project

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Request

Parameters:

{"path"=>"assets/javascripts/build/polyfills/dialog-polyfill.min","format"=>"js"}
```

**Session Dump**

```
_csrf_token: "phRgTk+ckBBhFegpIu+mwvkIJzd57rt4T6XZUE8Wee4="
session_id: "7f5e825832ba66bdc94ea27ab930d04c"
```

**Env Dump**

```
GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.1"
HTTP_ACCEPT: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: "gzip, deflate"
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: "en-us"
REMOTE_ADDR: "127.0.0.1"
REMOTE_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
SERVER_NAME: "localhost"
SERVER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you not pulling build/polyfills/* into your application.js manifest already using

//= require_tree .

? My understanding is that it's faster to render a single large CSS file than fetching multiple files. More info on manifest files [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives).